# Статическая переменная не отображается в Inspector-е

Tags: unity3d, static, unity3d-editor

У меня часто используемый метод `WriteInConsole`. И да он статический:

```cs
public class Functions : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameObject ConsolePrefab;

    public static void WriteInConsole(string message, GameObject Parent)
    {
        GameObject Console = Instantiate(ConsolePrefab, Parent.transform);
        Text Message = Console.transform.Find("Content").transform.Find("Text (Message)").GetComponent<Text>();
        Message.text = message;
    }
}
```

Так как метод статический, переменная `ConsolePrefab` которая в нём тоже должен быть статическим. И поскольку она Prefab проблем вроде не должен быть, всё складывается. Но не всё так хорошо... Поскольку я сделал переменную статическим, она не отображается в Inspector-е.

---

*Как решить эту проблему с инспектором? Или может быть скрипт как то изменить, чтобы можно было использовать метод прямо через class как в рисунке.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если прям совсем простой выход - сделайте экземплярное поле. В Awake назначьте его значение в статичное. Ни в каких Awake не обращайтесь к этому вашему статичному методу, чтобы случайно не вызвать его до инициализации поля. Соблюдайте правило - Awake для внутренней инициализации, Start - для инициализации с доступом наружу.

```
public class Functions : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializableField]
    GameObject _consolePrefab;

    public static GameObject ConsolePrefab;

    void Awake() => ConsolePrefab = _consolePrefab;

    public static void WriteInConsole(string message, GameObject Parent)
    {
        GameObject Console = Instantiate(ConsolePrefab, Parent.transform);
        Text Message = Console.transform.Find("Content").transform.Find("Text (Message)").GetComponent<Text>();
        Message.text = message;
    }
}
```